# Adding sub-tasks to stories in Confluence?

Tags: jira

I have just started as PMO Coordinator of several teams. All teams add sub-tasks to stories/requirements, and they do all this in Jira (create requirements/stories + DEV team add sub-tasks), and all of them do that their own way, without following any specific format for user story creation, with in many cases lead to confusion as requirements aro not clearly exposed.

So I wanted to use Confluence as a home for our stories. But my question is, how can I add sub-tasks to this stories? Is it possible to do so in Confluence? Or do you have any other ideas regarding how to unify requirements/stories creation across all teams? I just thought of confluence since in my previous jobs I used it and it is a good way of creating clear stories.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the goal is to have Confluence as home for stories/requirements and export them to Jira.

Comment: If you copy the content that is currently in Jira 1-to-1 into Confluence, what does that bring you? Or might it be better to reach a common agreement on how to write good requirements/stories regardless of the tool they are captured in?

Comment: Hmm actually there's no content in Jira currently, as stories/requirements are written almost by copy/pasting the Business requirements into Jira, so I wanted to implement another method of documenting Epics/Stories for upcoming projects, so I thought of Confluence and then exporting them to Jira for Devs to work on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sub-tasks in Jira are typically used for the 'how'

> how can I add sub-tasks to this stories? Is it possible to do so in Confluence?

Requirements should focus on 'what' the business needs and 'why'. Sub-tasks in Jira are meant for the Dev Team (as you yourself noted) to organize the work to be done into bite sized chunks - the 'how'. This is not part of the requirements.

> Or do you have any other ideas regarding how to unify
>   requirements/stories creation across all teams?

To unify requirements/stories creation across all teams, read my earlier answer here:
[Some steps to improve requirements communication](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/23606/agile-requirements-tracking/23609#23609).

If you need a hierarchical story structure, you can use Epics as the parent level and User Stories as children. Acceptance criteria developed in the discussion between dev team and PO/Stakeholders is a key part of the requirements. Not sure how keeping all this in Confluence will help.